# Suppress evaluation of knitr chunk options in custom language engine

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am writing a custom `knitr` language engine to support https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/469, and I would like users to be able to write R Markdown code chunks like this:

````
```{tar_target analysis, pattern = map(data)}
run_analysis(data)
```
````

I want to avoid evaluating the `pattern` argument because `map(data)` is a DSL in [`tar_target()`](https://docs.ropensci.org/targets/reference/tar_target.html) and not actual R code. But when I run the chunk, I get a "could not find function 'map'" error before control passes to the engine. Is it possible for me as the developer to call `substitute()` on the necessary options before `knitr` tries to evaluate them?

EDIT: thinking about supporting a wrapper to control special arguments to `tar_target()`:

````
```{tar_target analysis, tar_args = tar_args(pattern = map(data), error = "workspace")}
run_analysis(data)
```
````

Comment: You can use matching code fences with more than three backticks around your RMarkdown code chunk.

Comment: I’ve only had a cursory glance at the issue, would it be possible to export `map` (and maybe other functions) which, when invoked, return an unevaluated expression, similar to what `~` does? That way you wouldn’t prevent knitr evaluating the arguments but the outcome would be the same: you can still access the unevaluated version. Of course the challenge then is to expose these functions only to knitr, not to user code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. What do you think about the `tar_args()` wrapper in the edit to the OP? Would that be too awkward or burdensome for the user?

Comment: Honestly, if the wrapper could be avoided that would obviously be better. No idea whether that’s achievable with knitr.

Comment: Hmm... Looks like if `pattern` is a language object, then `knitr` automatically converts it to `"NA"`, even inside a `tar_args` list. So the user might just have to quote arguments on a case-by-case basis if we use chunk options. The only other alternative I can think of is to avoid chunk options altogether and use some kind of unidiomatic custom inline YAML to specify arguments to `tar_target()`.

Comment: The most reasonable option seems to be regular chunk options with the requirement that the user wrap quotes around `pattern` and `cue`. Not pretty, but it should work with the right documentation and informative error messages.

Comment: Wait, now I see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/142. There is an internal `eval_lang()` utility function that may allow this. I just need to figure out how to activate it.

Comment: I also had a look at https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/570. So in the case of `pattern` and `cue`, it looks like I need `knitr::opts_knit$set(eval.after = c("pattern", "cue"))` in combination with `eval = FALSE`. Now if I could just set `eval = FALSE` only for the custom language engines I create...